# Checking whether website has certificate C#

Tags: c#, selenium

is there any way to check whether website has any certificate? I tried to do this with Selenium Web Driver but I had some difficulties.
We want to automate navigation through several sites until we find one with certificate.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: whats kind of certificate?

Answer (score 0):

It should suffice to try to open the URL using https:// instead of http and if no exception is thrown (like certificate not from a trusted provider) or the page doesn't exist then you have a page with a valid SSL certificate.